# PHP - foreach loop and multidimensional array

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, foreach, nested-loops

There a lots of questions/answers here on SO about multidim arrays and foreach loops but I haven't found one that applies specifically to my case. Please advise if you think otherwise.

My array is structured as below, and is output to a CodeIgniter view:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array //this is the unique user ID
        (
            [name] => Joe Schmoe
            [cars] => Array
                (
                    [112] => Array //this is the unique car ID
                        (
                            [cars_name] => Honda
                            [cars_type] => Sedan
                            [cars_color] => White
                        )

                    [102] => Array
                        (
                            [cars_name] => Toyota
                            [cars_type] => Sedan
                            [cars_color] => Black
                        )

                    [113] => Array
                        (
                            [cars_name] => Nissan
                            [cars_type] => Coupe
                            [cars_color] => Red
                        )
                )
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Buck
            [cars] => Array
                (
                    [147] => Array
                        (
                            [cars_name] => Tesla
                            [cars_type] => Sedan
                            [cars_color] => Yellow
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Mike Mechanic
            [cars] => Array
                (
                    [140] => Array
                        (
                            [cars_name] => BMW
                            [cars_type] => SUV
                            [cars_color] => Blue
                        )

                    [145] => Array
                        (
                            [cars_name] => MB
                            [cars_type] => Sedan
                            [cars_color] => Gray
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

I need help building the nested `foreach` loops so I can have access to each one of the elements in the entire array.

I tried this nested `foreach` structure but it's a no go.

```
foreach ($results as $data):
    if (is_array($data)):
        foreach ($data as $value):
            if (is_array($value)):
                foreach ($value as $row):
                endforeach;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endif;
endforeach;

echo $row->cars_name //returns a non-object error
```

Anyone know how to put this nested loop together?

Thanks for helping, much appreciated.

Comment: I get a `Trying to get property of non-object` error when trying to echo an array element

Comment: That's because it is no object and you act like it is one. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: You're trying to access a loop variable outside of the loop. Put that echo inside the inner most foreach

Comment: wow someone downvoted without a reason or offering help? no love lost there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing $row from outside the loop. If you want to process each row, you should put that code (the echo) inside the loop.

An alternative would be to use [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php). That will call a callback function for each value in a multi dimensional array.

[edit]

The row you get is not an object either. It is still an array. Try to

```
echo $row['cars_name'];
```

Comment: thanks for the comment @goleztrol - i tried inside the loop and still get the same  `Trying to get property of non-object` error --

Comment: @torr `echo $row['cars_name'];` instead of `echo $row->cars_name`

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you..

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if(is_array($result['cars'])){
        foreach ($result['cars'] as $car) {
            echo $car['cars_name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Also you were trying to access an array element by class attribute access notation.